# OpenCL: kernel hangs forever unless I remove parameters

Tags: python, opencl, pyopencl

This is OpenCL 1.1 , using the Intel SDK (1.5 x64). PyOpenCL 2011.2. I'm on Linux (Fedora).

The following code prints `"DERP1"`, but nothing else.

```
import pyopencl as cl
import numpy
import struct

ctx = cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)
mf = cl.mem_flags

board = numpy.zeros((10, 24), dtype=numpy.int8)
board_buf = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=board)

can_move = numpy.zeros(1, dtype=numpy.int8)
can_move_buf = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_WRITE | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=can_move)

program = cl.Program(ctx, """
__kernel void can_move(
    __global const char *board,
    const char2 board_size,
    __global char *can_move)
{
    *can_move = 1;
}
""").build()

move = program.can_move(queue, board.shape, None,
    board_buf, #__global const char *board,
    struct.pack('bb', 10, 24), #__global const char2 board_size
    can_move_buf) #__global *can_move



result = numpy.empty_like(can_move)
print "DERP1"
move.wait()
print "DERP2"
cl.enqueue_copy(queue, result, can_move_buf)
print "DERP3"

print result
```

It prints `"DERP1"` and then keeps working.

However, if I remove the first or the second parameters (i.e. `board` or `board_size`), the program halts and prints `[1]` like I expect.

What is going on? How do I make this work the way I meant?

---

**edit:** `top` reports over 350% CPU usage consistently. If I replace the global_size from `board.shape` (i.e. `(10, 24)`) to `(1,)` (i.e. only one task in one dimension), then I get about 100% CPU usage. To me this indicates that this one task is running forever busy-looping without stopping, but I don't know why. For this one task, as with the 10*24 tasks, if I remove the first or second parameter, it halts.

---

**edit2:**: I'm pretty sure this is a problem with PyOpenCL? I ported the example as best as I can to C, the results of which can be found [here](http://codepad.org/J8nFTwzM), but the C example does not hang. Can anyone spot some difference or figure out the problem?

Comment: have you asked the pyopencl mailing list / maintainer.  when i used it, they were pretty responsive.

Comment: @andrewcooke Yes, after I narrowed it down to PyOpenCL I posted to the mailing list. See http://lists.tiker.net/pipermail/pyopencl/2012-April/001158.html

Comment: That is the output I get:  DERP1, DERP2, DERP3 and [1]

Comment: How did you resolve this?

Comment: I didn't AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

I cut and pasted your code into a text file and ran it on my system, and it ran just fine.

```
jmt@belle:~$ python djhang.py
DERP1
DERP2
DERP3
[1]
jmt@belle:~$
```

I did notice two things in your code that I don't see in example code or in my own.  I use tuples for sizes -- examples would be (64,) for a 1D kernel and (64,64,) for a 2D kernel.  Does that work for you?  Also, I put the wait() call directly after the program execution call.  The array creation should orthogonal to the OpenCL stuff but I just don't like having anything between them.

Hope that helps!